# React-native app stuck on splash screen, works fine on debug mode

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

My react-native app is running and everything is working fine when I run it in debug mode aka with `npx react-native run-android` but it gets stuck on splash-screen (doesn't crash) when trying to open the release builds either with `npx react-native run-android --variant=release` or by exporting apk with `assembleRelease` command on gradle.

Here's the log I was able to get by using `npx react-native log-andoid` command: [logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p8oi.png).

I can't figure it out what's the issue, is it regarding `react-native-gesture-handler`? If yes, then why this error/log doesn't come up in debug builds?

Edit: This log appears in android studio:

```
2022-05-27 08:42:48.087 0-0/? E/init: updatable process 'console' exited 4 times in 4 minutes
2022-05-27 08:42:48.093 0-0/? I/init: processing action (sys.init.updatable_crashing=1) from (/system/etc/init/flags_health_check.rc:10)
2022-05-27 08:42:48.094 0-0/? I/init: starting service 'exec 3578 (/system/bin/flags_health_check UPDATABLE_CRASHING)'...
2022-05-27 08:42:48.097 0-0/? I/init: SVC_EXEC service 'exec 3578 (/system/bin/flags_health_check UPDATABLE_CRASHING)' pid 2148 (uid 1000 gid 1000+0 context default) started; waiting...
2022-05-27 08:42:48.118 2148-2148/? I/flags_health_check: ServerConfigurableFlagsReset reset_mode value: 1
2022-05-27 08:42:48.118 2148-2148/? I/flags_health_check: ServerConfigurableFlagsReset updatable crashing detected, resetting flags.
2022-05-27 08:42:48.102 0-0/? I/init: Service 'exec 3578 (/system/bin/flags_health_check UPDATABLE_CRASHING)' (pid 2148) exited with status 0 waiting took 0.005000 seconds
2022-05-27 08:42:48.105 0-0/? I/init: Sending signal 9 to service 'exec 3578 (/system/bin/flags_health_check UPDATABLE_CRASHING)' (pid 2148) process group...
2022-05-27 08:42:48.107 0-0/? I/libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 1000 pid 2148 in 0ms
2022-05-27 08:42:48.330 491-491/? E/netmgr: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:network' service: Invalid argument
2022-05-27 08:42:48.330 491-491/? E/netmgr: Failed to open QEMU pipe 'qemud:network': Invalid argument
2022-05-27 08:42:48.640 495-495/? E/wifi_forwarder: qemu_pipe_open_ns:62: Could not connect to the 'pipe:qemud:wififorward' service: Invalid argument
2022-05-27 08:42:48.640 495-495/? E/wifi_forwarder: RemoteConnection failed to initialize: RemoteConnection failed to open pipe
2022-05-27 08:42:51.339 0-0/? E/ICMPv6: RA: ndisc_router_discovery failed to add default route
2022-05-27 08:42:53.074 0-0/? I/init: starting service 'console'...
2022-05-27 08:42:53.087 0-0/? I/init: Service 'console' (pid 2152) exited with status 0
2022-05-27 08:42:53.091 0-0/? I/init: Sending signal 9 to service 'console' (pid 2152) process group...
2022-05-27 08:42:53.094 0-0/? I/libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 2000 pid 2152 in 0ms
2022-05-27 08:42:53.098 0-0/? E/init: updatable process 'console' exited 4 times in 4 minutes
```

And in project errors this [log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32YPe.png)

Answer (score 0):

try to run your project with Android Studio, i think you will get some errors here

Comment: I have updated with logs from android studio, could you please check again?

Answer (score 0):

try adding org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:3.0.10 in your dependency list in the app level build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-json:3.0.10'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after 3 days of suffering I found out what's wrong.

So, a couple of days ago I opened the project on Android Studio and clicked on a popup that said `upgrade gradle version` which ended up updating my gradle version from `7.0.4` to `7.1.2` causing these problems